# Set email recipient based on form selection

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I managed to cobble together a script based on different things I've seen on here, but the script always sends an email to the first recipient group, so I'm guessing something is wrong in my "if" "else if" section.
Thanks for your help!

```
//Script to email selected location about submissions on the Classroom Collection Form using trigger onFormSubmit
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

function initialize() {
  var triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
  for(var i in triggers) {
    ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(triggers[i]);
  }
ScriptApp.newTrigger("email")
  .forSpreadsheet(sheet)
  .onFormSubmit()
  .create();
}

function email() {
  var row = sheet.getActiveRange().getRowIndex();
  var recipient;
  var branchChoice = sheet.getRange("K"+row).getValue();
  if (branchChoice == "Fairfield Inside"||"Fairfield Drive Thru"){recipient = "user1@lane.org, user2@lane.org, user7@lane.org"}
  else if (branchChoice == "Hamilton Inside"||"Hamilton Drive Thru"){recipient = "user3@lane.org, user4@lane.org, user7@lane.org"}
  else if (branchChoice == "Oxford Inside"||"Oxford Drive Thru"){recipient = "user5@lane.org, user7@lane.org"}
  else if (branchChoice == "Bookmobile Drop Off"){recipient = "user6@lane.org, user7@lane.org"}
  var subject = "New Classroom Collection Request";
  var message = "<HTML><BODY>"
                  + "<P><B>New Request Information Recieved - </B>"+ sheet.getRange("A"+row).getValue()
                  + "<P><B>Teacher Name: </B>" + sheet.getRange ("B"+row).getValue()
                  + "<P><B>School: </B>" + sheet.getRange ("C"+row).getValue()
                  + "<P><B>Teacher's Email: </B>" + sheet.getRange ("D"+row).getValue()
                  + "<P><B>Phone: </B>" + sheet.getRange ("E"+row).getValue()
                  + "<P><B>Teacher Barcode: </B>" + sheet.getRange ("F"+row).getValue()
                  + "<P><B>Grade: </B>" + sheet.getRange ("G"+row).getValue()
                  + "<P><B>Room Number: </B>" + sheet.getRange ("H"+row).getValue()
                  + "<P><B>Pick-Up Month: </B>" + sheet.getRange ("I"+row).getValue()
                  + "<P><B>Pick-Up Day: </B>" + sheet.getRange ("J"+row).getValue()
                  + "<P><B>Branch Pick-Up Location: </B>" + sheet.getRange ("K"+row).getValue()
                  + "<P><B>Subjects: </B>" + sheet.getRange ("L"+row).getValue()
                  + "<P><B>Collection Should Include: </B>" + sheet.getRange ("M"+row).getValue()
                  + "<P><B>Specific Titles Requested: </B>" + sheet.getRange ("N"+row).getValue()
                  + "<P><B>Reading Levels: </B>" + sheet.getRange ("O"+row).getValue()
                  + "<P><B>Number of Items Needed: </B>" + sheet.getRange ("P"+row).getValue()
                  + "</HTML></BODY>";

                  MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, "", {htmlBody: message});
}
```

Comment: I ended up switching to indexOf because the || didn't seem to be functioning correctly. If an option listed after the OR was selected the recipient would be undefined. `if (branchChoice.indexOf("Fairfield")>-1)`

Comment: May be it needed some use of "trim()" on "branchChoice"... But you right, it seems to me that it's better to compare string using "indexOf"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is caused by "Fairfield Drive Thru", which is always "true" in js understanding.
Try add parentheses to your conditions like :

```
if (branchChoice == ("Fairfield Inside"||"Fairfield Drive Thru"))
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. As someone who works off other peoples examples I don't think I would have ever caught that mistake.